# "Unable to open a display" while rendering in AWS ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gpu, rendering, ec2-api-tools

[image]

I am unable to figure out where I am wrong while rendering in ec2 instance

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
p2.xlarge
x86_64

I have followed every single step in https://fajrulf.medium.com/how-to-do-blender-rendering-using-amazon-aws-gpu-28d396dc66a9 tutorial.

I have also tried to install cuda from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Comment: how are you connecting to the ec2? Have you done X11 forwarding incase you are ssh into the box

Comment: some thing require a "connected" display to the GPU. hence the use & sale of duty plugs. how ever this is not possible in the cloud. You can fake this as per this answer -> https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150526/blender-2-8-aws-ec2-command-line-eevee-render/150532#150532